# Why is docker volume create and rm not symmetrical?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

Docker volume create works like this:

```
docker volume create --name v1
v1
```

Docker volume remove works like this:

```
docker volume rm v1
v1
```

So why does `docker volume create` need the `--name` parameter?

Comment: Cross reference: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully it will be symmetrical soon, with the current `--name` parameter supported for backward compatibility:
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23345

Comment: `--name` is not needed for `docker volume create` as of Docker 1.13